Is biological stress related to COVID lockdown policies a better explanation of excess pandemic deaths than COVID infection?
The following claim was made on the newsletter of Children's Health Defence (the organisation founded by RFK Jr partly to promote his anti-vaccine agenda):

Most excess deaths during the COVID-19 pandemic can be linked to biological stress brought on by coordinated and large-scale mandates and medical assaults — ranging from lockdowns to vaccination to denial of antibiotics and antivirals — according to a paper released Monday by excess mortality researcher Denis Rancourt, Ph.D.

The referenced paper by Denis Rancourt appears to be non peer-reviewed and self published.
The key argument appears to be that specific non-COVID infections promoted by vaccine mandates, lockdown policy and other anti-COVID interventions can be shown to have killed far more people than COVID itself by encouraging other infections in the stressed population.
This is a much more specific claim than some previously addressed claims here that lockdown policies cause more deaths than COVID itself.
Obviously, the source of the claim—a known anti-vaccine organisation—is not inherently trustworthy. But it does seem to be newsworthy and notable having even reached Bluesky as a topic related to the Trump nominee who could soon be in charge of US Health policy.
Do the claims in the Rancourt paper have any credibility?

Dear HNQ Visitors, welcome to Skeptics! Do not post your opinions in chat.

No. The underlying idea is the terrain theory of disease, slightly repackaged. The germ theory of disease is supported by 200 years of experimental data. On the other hand, you have this self published manuscript:

The idea that epidemics, pandemics and seasonal mortality are due to environmental and health-status factors (often discussed in terms of so-called terrain theory vs germ theory) rather than contagion is not new. In fact, it is as old as epidemiology itself (“epidemic constitutions of the atmosphere”, Sydenham, 1676). My contribution here is [...]

The mechanism and etiology of COVID-19 has been well established. We have data for it. So much data. The majority of this self published manuscript is a poorly written gish gallop. However, it does have a clear single axiom that it starts with: that COVID-19 deaths were not caused by SARS-COV2 infection.

The hypothesis of a specific spreading viral respiratory pathogen causing excess allcause mortality during the Covid period (2020-2022) is contrary to and disproved by two main direct observations

Every citation for this 'counter-evidence' has a shared author:

These basic incompatibilities have been previously reported (Rancourt, 2020, 2022; Rancourt et al., 2020, 2021a, 2021b, 2022a, 2022b, 2023a, 2023b, 2024). For example, in India there was no detectable excess all-cause mortality until the vaccine was first
rolled out starting in March 2021 (Rancourt, 2022)

All of the resulting conclusions require this axiom to be true. It is not.
While it is certainly the case that some of the excess mortality was not caused directly by SARS-COV2 infection, that excess mortality is attributed to diminished health care availability, because of the number of people who required intervention health care as a result of COVID-19. Vaccine safety has been asked and answered here (so many times).

You might need to show why that is the underlying idea in the claim as it doesn't seem obvious to me.

It's verbatim written in the paper. It's not hidden. The author's an anti-germ theory crank.

I haven't read the whole paper, but I saw he was attributing increased mortality to bacterial pneumonia. Surely that requires Germ Theory to make sense. I appreciate it reads like he started with a conclusion and came up with a hypothesis to reach it, but calling the conclusion an axiom seems to be begging the question

This manuscript concludes the lethal thing that killed everyone was 'medical assaults' and 'lockdowns'. That it could not be SARS-COV2 is the axiom this manuscript starts with. The terrain theory explanation for bacterial pneumonia is that it's a happy bacteria that's always there in your lungs which you have enraged into a malignant phenotype with your vaccines and by not going to the mall.

@Oddthinking just because one thing (Covid itself) is a major cause of death does not mean other conditions caused by its effects (like immune system failure) like bacterial pneumonia can't be factors. And those deaths would be attributed to Covid as that's the underlying cause, except of cause by quacks who claim Covid doesn't exist.

@jwenting: Not sure of your point here. I was trying to strengthen CJR's post against being a strawman. CJR has responded by explaining how Terrain Theory works, which addresses my Germ Theory part. I am still unsure of the "axiom" part. While we can cynically speculate that Rancourt started with a conclusion, and worked backwards to try to support it rather than following the data, that doesn't belong in an answer because we can't empirically support it.

@Oddthinking just adding a note that just because one thing happens there can't be other things happening as well so them stating that pneumonia happened a lot isn't a lie but a misrepresentation of the actual cause of death (whether deliberate or through misunderstanding I'll leave in the middle).

@Oddthinking The title and summaries in the question of the underlying manuscript are inaccurate. This work starts from the idea (that the author claims is already proven and is therefore axiomatic to this manuscript) that COVID-19 is not a respiratory pandemic and SARS-COV2 did not kill people. The work is then an attempt to explain where the mountains of dead bodies (in excess mortality) came from. The analysis can be dismissed as unsound if COVID-19 is a respiratory pandemic caused by SARS-COV2.

You make it sound like you've demonstrated the claim in the question title to be false.  What you've actually done (as you acknowledge in the comments) is point out that the source material made a very different claim, and failed to provide anything like adequate support for that different claim.
For that reason, I think Schwern picked a considerably better headline for his answer.

The evidence does not support the claim.
This is a case of where the stated question/claim is sensible, biological stress is a real thing, but the evidence is so bananas it cannot be used to meaningfully answer the question.
Rancourt goes so far beyond the norms and mixes in other discredited ideas making it a gish gallop slurry. Dr. Rancourt's work on COVID is self-referencing and not peer-reviewed, he primarily cites himself, making it not much better than a rant by "some guy on the internet", just more sciency-sounding. It's not evidence for anything.
Finally, Rancourt does not only question the cause of the COVID pandemic, but every viral respiratory pandemic.
What is Rancourt's work on COVID?
The following is from his essay There Was No Pandemic.

Here are my conclusions, from our detailed studies of all-cause mortality in the COVID period, in combination with socio-economic and vaccine-rollout data:

If there had been no pandemic propaganda or coercion, and governments and the medical establishment had simply gone on with business as usual, then there would not have been any excess mortality
There was no pandemic causing excess mortality
Measures caused excess mortality
COVID-19 vaccination caused excess mortality


And from his summary in Medical Hypothesis: Respiratory epidemics and pandemics without viral transmission...

In this paper, I systematically present many facets (based on the existing scientific literature) of my overall hypothesis whereby the Covid-period pandemic of mortality was a pandemic of transmissionless self-infection bacterial pneumonias induced by
biological stress (in the sense of medical researcher Hans Selye, which includes psychological stress) arising from the coordinated and large-scale mandates, measures, so-called responses, and medical assaults including testing, diagnostic bias, isolation, denial of treatment (especially antibiotics for pneumonia), mechanical ventilation, sedation, experimental and improper treatments, and vaccination.

Rancourt entirely lays the excess mortality (10-20 million people) on factors other than the virus itself. He relies entirely on his own conclusions based solely on the mortality data ignoring other evidence and work. Once he's dismissed viral transmission as a possibility, he grasps at many novel hypotheses to explain the excess deaths.
Rancourt states the vaccine itself killed people.

In this way, we showed that the vaccination campaign in India caused the deaths of 3.7 million fragile residents. In Western countries, we quantified the average all-ages rate of death to be 1 death for every 2000 injections, to increase exponentially with age (doubling every additional 5 years of age), and to be as large as 1 death for every 100 injections for those 80 years and older. We estimated that the vaccines had killed 13 million worldwide.

Rancourt claims pathogens have never caused a pandemics.
He proposes a lot of alternatives such as volcanoes:

Historic pandemics may also be explained by large sudden natural environmental changes, such as large explosive volcanic eruptions...

Or that socio-economic collapse caused the Black Death, not the other way around:

...a competing or complimentary thesis is that the great plagues of the Middle Ages (including the Black Death) were induced by socio-economic collapse, in great waves that repeat the sequence

He proposes that there is no evidence pandemics are caused by new pathogens:

Otherwise, in a stable society, mortality is extremely robust and is not subject to large rapid changes. There is no empirical evidence that large changes in mortality can be induced by sudden appearances of new pathogens. In the contemporary era of the dominant human species, humanity is its worst enemy, not nature.

He claims the 1918 Flu was not caused by a virus, but by bacterial pneumonia:

The large 1918 mortality event, which was recruited to be a textbook viral respiratory disease pandemic (“H1N1”), occurred prior to the inventions of antibiotics and the electron microscope, under horrific post-war public-sanitation and economic-stress conditions. The 1918 deaths have been proven by histopathology of preserved lung tissue to have been caused by bacterial pneumonia. This is shown in several independent and non-contested published studies.

And that respiratory viruses have never causes a pandemic:

3.5 Has a pandemic-causing viral respiratory pathogen ever
existed?
At this point, it is not unreasonable to ask whether the viral spread theory of respiratory
epidemics and pandemics has any relevance whatsoever to the observed phenomena.

Rancourt makes some very questionable statements about the spread of COVID.

In fact, the very notion of “spread” during the COVID period is rigorously disproved by the temporal and spatial variations of excess all-cause mortality, everywhere that it is sufficiently quantified, worldwide. For example, the presumed virus that killed 1.3 million poor and disabled residents of the USA did not cross the more-than-thousand-kilometer land border with Canada, despite continuous and intense economic exchanges.

COVID certainly got into Canada, with 5 million cases and 55,000 deaths, so I'm not sure what he's talking about. Perhaps that Canada has lower death rate than the US? He provides no citations.
Rancourt states that people's own microbiome killed them
Rancourt refers to "transmissionless self-infection bacterial pneumonias" as the cause of a lot of things. The idea that your body already has bad germs in it. Normally it can keep them at bay, but when it gets "stressed" it cannot.
Both biological stress and the microbiome are real things, but Rancourt goes so far as to make them the sole cause straying into germ theory denialism.

I end this section by suggesting that transmissionless mechanisms for pandemics and epidemics have incorrectly been overlooked and underappreciated. Basically, a person’s own microbiome is enough to cause virtually anything, under changing
conditions. The bias towards pathogen-transmission mechanisms exhibited by clinicians, epidemiologists and public-health managers, as the dominant or driving mechanism of pandemics and epidemics, has evolved historically (Martin and Martin-
Granel, 2006), and in my opinion is not justified. In fact, it is disproved by epidemiological all-cause mortality studies (Section 3.3.1). The said bias, including the associated and widespread diagnostic bias, relies disproportionately on molecular tests of bodily fluids and blood, which are not as specific as claimed, and are not sufficiently and rigorously validated, despite their comprehensive promotion by the industry

Let's talk about section 3.3.1 which he claims disproves pathogen-transmission mechanisms.
Enter the Rancourt-verse.
Rancourt loves to cite Rancourt. The referenced paper Medical Hypothesis: Respiratory epidemics and pandemics without viral transmission is self-published and not peer reviewed. In one sub-section alone "3.3.1 Ruled out: SARS-CoV-2 as a primary cause of death" he cites himself sixteen times! Some of them haven't even been published yet "(Rancourt et al., in preparation)".
Here's a sample (bold is mine).

The hypothesis of a specific spreading viral respiratory pathogen causing excess all-cause mortality during the Covid period (2020-2022) is contrary to and disproved by two main direct observations:
i. It is incompatible with the large country-to-country heterogeneity of age and frailty adjusted (P-score) excess all-cause mortality rate (e.g., Rancourt et al., 2024, their sections 5.5 and 5.7; and see COVID-19 Forecasting Team, 2022,re heterogeneity of IFR).
ii. It is incompatible with the country-to-country spatiotemporal pattern of deaths,including the phenomenon of not crossing national borders. There is no evidence of spread, only local (by country) and time-specific assaults that do not geo-temporally evolve (e.g., Rancourt et al., 2024, their sections 4.11, 4.12 and 5.6).
These basic incompatibilities have been previously reported (Rancourt, 2020, 2022; Rancourt et al., 2020, 2021a, 2021b, 2022a, 2022b, 2023a, 2023b, 2024). For example, in India there was no detectable excess all-cause mortality until the vaccine was first rolled out starting in March 2021 (Rancourt, 2022).
The said basic incompatibilities, while already proven, are corroborated in a high spatial resolution spatiotemporal hemispheric-scale study by Hickey et al. (in preparation), and
for Canada (Rancourt et al., in preparation).

Rancourt, Rancourt, Rancourt et al., Rancourt.
A doctorate doesn't make you a medical doctor.
Normally focusing on the people behind the evidence makes for a poor answer, but in this instance everything relies on just one person. Good science relies on discourse and consensus and multiple points of view. Here we have just one, Denis Rancourt. So I think it's fair to ask who is Denis Rancourt, PhD?
Denis Rancourt has a PhD in physics from the University of Ottawa. He taught physics and he seems to have done some good work in physics.

I am an accomplished interdisciplinary scientist and physicist, and a former tenured Full Professor of physics and lead scientist, originally at the University of Ottawa.

He has chosen to dabble in other fields such as climate science and epidemiology. This is fine, if it remains good science. That means accepting critiques, peer review, honest dialogue, etc. Unfortunately, rather than accepting criticism of his work he is crying "censorship".

I have written over 30 scientific reports relevant to COVID, starting April 18, 2020 for the Ontario Civil Liberties Association (ocla.ca/covid), and recently for a new non-profit corporation (correlation‑canada.org/research). Presently, all my work and interviews about COVID are documented on my website created to circumvent the barrage of censorship (denisrancourt.ca).

These are not peer reviewed works. He's working outside his field. So Dr. Rancourt's work on COVID is not much better than "some guy on the Internet". As a result, he falls back to argument by incredulity.

Is humanity really at risk of catastrophic near-extinction events from mutations (accidental or designed molecular sequences) in relatively small genetic macromolecules that spontaneously enter and mega-replicate in living cells in our
healthy bodies? I cannot find the receipts.

Rancourt's other dabbling.
Rancourt is also a climate change denier.
He was convicted of defaming a fellow professor after he refused to participate in his own trial claiming the judge was biased; I think it's fair to say he doesn't take criticism well.
Conclusion
I'll leave this with Rancourt's own words, where he gets so close to figuring it out...

Otherwise, in a stable society, mortality is extremely robust and is not subject to large rapid changes. There is no empirical evidence that large changes in mortality can be induced by sudden appearances of new pathogens. In the contemporary era of the dominant human species, humanity is its worst enemy, not nature.

Indeed it is, Dr. Rancourt.

Is he assuming that country mortality data is equally reliable to back his heterogeneity claim? That is demonstrably false and a pretty dumb basis for a critical piece of evidence?. –

@matt_black He's making a lot of assumptions and ignoring a lot of evidence; his COVID work is built own his own pet hypothesizes with the occasional misapplication of other's work. If he was a well-meaning dabbler, he'd listen to critiques and accept peer review to improve his work, but he considers them bias and censorship. Yet he's sciency-sounding and has a PhD, so he's found an audience in the conspiracy crowd. Thus ever inward does he spiral.

@matt_black Which is to say it's hard to point at just one thing wrong with his hypothesises; it's all a slurry. If you'd like to know about a specific aspect of his work, I'd suggest asking another more focused question.

This seems like poisoning the well, rather than engaging with the evidence and reasoning in the sources. Or am I missing a non-ad-hominem connection between Rancourt being a climate change denier and his arguments on this subject?

@Sneftel The Britannica definition of ad-hominem is "type of argument or attack that appeals to prejudice or feelings or irrelevantly impugns another person’s character instead of addressing the facts or claims made by the latter" (emphasis mine).  So the question is whether climate change denial is relevant to germ theory denial, vaccine denial, and COVID denial.  I don't think it's unreasonable to suggest that the wider his range of refusal to look at evidence is, the less credence should be given to any single claim.

@Sneftel ... It becomes relevant when it speaks to the possibility of a general character trait existing which makes him incapable of carrying out valid scientific effort based on evidence.  At that point, it is irrelevant even whether his claim is true or not, because that claim would inherently be based on invalid reasoning (the "stopped clock" principle) and would not allow anyone to make useful future predictions/progress.

@Schwern I disagree slightly on the point that it is hard to find "just one thing" wrong. It looks easy to me to point out many single argument or data points that completely undermine his thread of argument.

@Graham Are you suggesting that when evaluating whether a conclusion properly proceeds from a particular set of premises, the character of the person making the conclusion should be taken into account?

@sneftel It should when the aspect of the character that's being taken into account is their history of coming up with absurd conclusions from already faulty premises.

@Shadur-don't-feed-the-AI So you’re content to heuristically evaluate the conclusions based on the person’s credibility, rather than directly? Why do you feel this should be preferred to a more rational approach?

This person isn't using anything resembling the scientific method is not an ad hominem, and directly goes to conclusions. That's not character.

@CJR That sounds like a good answer, as long as it’s coupled with particular examples of how some of the conclusions weren’t scientifically reached. Of course, without that, it wouldn’t be a valid answer at all.

@Sneftel You're aware of the concept of sealioning, aren't you? Yes, the character of the person absolutely must be taken into account for whether you look more deeply into their claims, because if they generally aren't taking part in good faith and with appropriate standards of reasoning, it's perfectly valid to refuse to waste your time on them.

@Graham It’s reasonable to personally and subjectively discount someone’s views based on how credible you find them. But that’s not the standard for answers here.

This is a great answer. I will note that in academic literature it is not at all uncommon to cite yourself. I don't exactly have a large body of work and I still have a couple of self-citations. Your new work often builds on or is at least related to your old work. However, when you are citing only yourself or almost only yourself, then it starts to raise questions to put it mildly.

This is pure ad hominem fallacy. Einstein was wrong about some things. Newton was wrong about a lot of things. Freud was a pseudoscientist. That doesn't invalidate their successful theories. It isn't enough to say Rancourt carries out pseudoscience or that he is wrong is some other areas to show he is wrong in this particular one. It is a reason to be skeptical; but it isn't the empirical data required to reach a conclusion. The HNQ-votes aren't helping here.

@Oddthinking It is not. Refusing to participate in good scientific practices like peer-reviewing might be perceived as ad-hominem, while it is not.

@usr1234567 It's ironic that you're making naked, unsupported assertions, no? Given that that's the primary objection to the source here?

Karry Mullis believed in Astrology, denied the link between HIV and AIDS and considered Ozone Depletion a myth. Nevertheless, his invention of PCR was a stroke of genius for which he deservedly received a Nobel prize. We should always  evaluate the work, not the character of the person doing the work. I don't care how big of a crank someone is, if they come up with a good idea, they came up with a good idea. So this answer doesn't seem to be addressing the question at all. Since Rancourt clearly is a crank, we can take apart his arguments.

@terdon I have evaluated the work. Mullis and Rancourt both did good work in their fields (Mullis was a biochemist), and then decided to dabble outside their expertise. Rancourt's work on COVID is a self-referencing gish-gallop of unreviewed assertions, and CJR already covered more. As we say here, the evidence does not support the claim. If you want you can ask a more focused claim, but check it hasn't already been answered.

@terdon From yours and other's comments, I realized I took it as given that Rancourt's work is a gish-gallop. I've reworked the answer to focus on the many, many, many claims he makes about COVID, pandemics in general, virology, and  volcanoes.

@usr1234567: Asserting that a claim is wrong not based on the evidence for and against the claim, but based on disapproval of the person making the claim is text book ad hominem attack, not merely the perception of one. This answer is about Rancourt, not about COVID-19.

@Oddthinking I've revised the answer to focus on Rancourt's own goop of unsupported and self-referencial claims and jumps to conclusions in the linked paper, there's more than enough. I'm only going to address the issues with using the paper as evidence for anything, as I understand is ok on skeptics. Let me know if you still have issues with the answer and I'll try to address them.

I seem to recall that on Skeptics, the answer is supposed to address only the actual claim made by the source, not all the facets of the title question as it relates to the subject matter.  I like this answer because it acknowledges that the broader question has gone unaddressed, which is something the other (higher-voted) answer did not do.

Thanks for the edit, @Schwern, that's much better! -1 converted to +1. To be clear, I absolutely agreed with everything in the original version too, I just felt that it wasn't demonstrating why this person is a crank only that they are.
